# Why can't Application Type Event Sibling Communicate?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, lightning-experience

I have this Event named - "**productAddItem**", an Application Type -

```
<aura:event type="application">
    <aura:attribute name="products" type="String" />
</aura:event>
```

with Parent Component "**Product.cmp**"-

```
<aura:component>
    <c:Middleman />
    <c:productForm />
</aura:component>
```

Sibling 1  "**Middleman.cmp**"-

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="var" type="String" default="VAL" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="addProduct" type="c:productAddItem" />
    <ui:button label="AddProduct" press="{!c.handleAddProducto}" />
</aura:component>
```

Sibling 1 COntroller "**MiddlemanController.js**" -

```
({
handleAddProducto : function(component, event, helper) {
    var products = component.get("v.var");
    var createEvent = component.getEvent("addProduct");
    createEvent.setParams({"products" : products});
    createEvent.fire();
}
})
```

Sibling 2 Component "**productForm.cmp**"-

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="var" type="String" default="VAL" />
<aura:registerEvent name="addProduct" type="c:productAddItem" />
<ui:button label="AddProduct" press="{!c.handleAddProducto}" />
</aura:component>
```

Sibling 2 COntroller "**productFormController.js**"-

```
({
handleAddProducto : function(component, event, helper) {
    var products = component.get("v.var");
    var createEvent = component.getEvent("addProduct");
    createEvent.setParams({"products" : products});
    createEvent.fire();
}
})
```

When I am Firing the Event from Middleman, it doesn't get handled in productForm Component. What could be the Issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of this which needs to be fixed:-
1. Need to add event handler in productForm Component.
2. Ned to correct the way of firing of application event.

```
var createEvent = $A.get("e.c:productAddItem");
```

Middleman.cmp

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="var" type="String" default="VAL" />
<aura:registerEvent name="addProduct" type="c:productAddItem" />
<ui:button label="AddProduct" press="{!c.handleAddProducto}" />
</aura:component>
```

MiddlemanController.js

```
 ({
    handleAddProducto : function(component, event, helper) {
    var products = component.get("v.var");
    var createEvent = $A.get("e.c:productAddItem");
    createEvent.setParams({"products" : products});
    createEvent.fire();
 }
})
```

productForm.cmp

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="var" type="String" default="VAL" />
<aura:handler event="c.productAddItem" action="{!c.handleAddProducto}"/>
</aura:component>
```

productFormController.js

```
({
   handleAddProducto : function(component, event, helper) {
   var capturedAppEvent = event.getParam("products");
   alert("Hello "+capturedAppEvent);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **MiddleMan** and **productForm** components are completely independent and have no knowledge of each other, so they need to communicate using Events.

Both of your components have a **handleAddProductTo** function which is firing the **addProduct** product event, but neither of them are listening to this event.

To fix this you'll need to add an event handler to **productForm.cmp**:

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute name="var" type="String" default="VAL" />
  <aura:registerEvent name="addProduct" type="c:productAddItem" />
  <aura:handler event="c:productAddItem" action="{!c.handleProductAddItemEvent}"/>
  <ui:button label="AddProduct" press="{!c.handleAddProducto}" />
</aura:component>
```

And in your **productFormController.js** you need to add another function to handle this:

```
({
  handleProductAddItemEvent: function(component, event, helper) {
    // handle the event as you need in here
  },

  handleAddProducto : function(component, event, helper) {
      // as before
  }
})
```

You'll need to consider that your **productForm.handleAddProductto** implementation also fires this event which means the new handler will be called then too, which may or not be the behaviour you want.